# Remove non-numeric characters except points, commas and '$'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a function to remove all characters except numbers + characters: '$', '.' and ','.

How can I do this?

Comment: The easiest way here would be using a regular expression

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
> 'worth $12,345.00 dollars'.replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, '')
"$12,345.00"
```

This is the answer you asked for. I would not recommend it for extracting currencies, since it can suffer from problems like this:

```
> 'A set of 12 worth between $123 and $456. A good buy.'.replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, '')
"12$123$456.."
```

If you want to just extract expressions of a currency-like form, you could do:

```
> 'set of 12 worth between $123.00 and $45,678'.match(/\$[0-9,]+(?:\.\d\d)?/g)
["$123.00", "$45,678"]
```

If you need more complicated matching (e.g. you'd just like to extract the dollar value and ignore the cent value) you could do something like [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex) for example:

```
> var regex = /\$([0-9,]+)(?:\.(\d\d))?/g;
> while (true) {
>     var match = regex.exec('set of 12 worth between $123.00 and $45,678');
>     if (match === null)
>         break;
>     console.log(match);
> }
["$123.00", "123", "00"]
["$45,678", "45,678", undefined]
```

(Thus be careful, javascript regexp objects are not immutable/final objects, but have state and can be used for iteration as demonstrated above. You thus cannot "reuse" a regexp object. Even passing `myRegex2 = RegExp(myRegex)` will mix state; a very poor language decision for the constructor. See the addendum on how to properly clone regexes in javascript.) You can rewrite the above as a very exotic for-loop if you'd like:

```
var myString = 'set of 12 worth between $123.00 and $45,678';
var regex = '\$([0-9,]+)(?:\.(\d\d))?';

for(var match, r=RegExp(regex,'g'); match=regex.exec(myString) && match!==null; )
    console.log(match);
```

---

*addendum - Why you can't reuse javascript RegExp objects*

Bad language design, demonstrating how state is reused:

```
var r=/(x.)/g
var r2 = RegExp(r)

r.exec('xa xb xc')
["xa", "xa"]
r2.exec('x1 x2 x3')
["x2", "x2"]
```

How to properly clone a regex in javascript (you have to define it with a string):

```
var regexTemplate = '(x.)'

var r = RegExp(regexTemplate, 'g')
var r2 = RegExp(regexTemplate, 'g')

r.exec('xa xb xc')
["xa", "xa"]
r2.exec('x1 x2 x3')
["x1", "x1"]
```

If you wish to programmatically preserve flags such as `'g'`, you can probably use `regexTemplate = ['(x.)', 'g']; RegExp.apply(this, regexTemplate)`.

Comment: thanks. I only used the first line but it will all probably help me in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to allow someone to type such values in a textbox then [jQuery Numeric](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/) is a nice plugin that does exactly what you want,